# Creating boxes around items in Tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have the following Tikz picture:

```
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
        \matrix (tree) [%
          matrix of nodes,
          minimum size=1cm,
          column sep=2.5cm,
          row sep=1cm,
        ]
        {
            $v_1$ &        & $v_3$ & $f_2$ & $v_5$ \\
                  &  $f_1$ &       &       &       \\
            $v_2$ &        & $v_4$ &       &       \\
        };
        \draw[->] (tree-1-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [near end,above, rounded corners] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [near end,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [near start,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [near start,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (tree-1-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [near end,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-1-4) -- (tree-1-5) node [near start,above] {$1$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

Is it possible to get boxes around the `$v_i$` and `$f_j$`? For instance circles?
I would like to have different boxes for the `$v_i$` and `$f_j$`, because they have a different meaning.

I'm new to Tikz btw.

Kind regards,
Jens

Comment: You can add `nodes={circle,draw}` to the matrix style.

Comment: @Kpym Please add an answer :) Avoid solutions in comments.

Comment: @JouleV you can do it, I have no time now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like different boxes for the $v_i$ and $f_j$. And I presume that this is not possible in setting the matrix style. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you want to have the same "box" for all nodes

You can add option `nodes={draw,circle}` if you want all nodes to be in circle "box":

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
        \matrix (tree) [%
          matrix of nodes,
          minimum size=1cm,
          column sep=2.5cm,
          row sep=1cm,
          nodes={draw,circle}
        ]
        {
            $v_1$ &        & $v_3$ & $f_2$ & $v_5$\\
                   &  $f_1$ &       &       &      \\
            $v_2$  &        & $v_4$ &       &      \\
        };
        \draw[->] (tree-1-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [near end,above, rounded corners] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [near end,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [near start,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [near start,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (tree-1-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [near end,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (tree-1-4) -- (tree-1-5) node [near start,above] {$1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All credits go to [Kpym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9335/kpym), and this nice proposal is shown in this answer by the author's request.

#### If you want different styles for different types of nodes

using `matrix` is still ok, but it is more complicated. I propose a normal solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,circle}]
            \node (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$};
            \node (v2) at (0,-2) {$v_2$};
            \node (v3) at (5,0) {$v_3$};
            \node (v4) at (5,-2) {$v_4$};
            \node (v5) at (10,0) {$v_5$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,rectangle}]
            \node (f1) at (2.5,-1) {$f_1$};
            \node (f2) at (7.5,0) {$f_2$};
        \end{scope}
        \draw[->] (v1) -- (f1) node [near end,above, rounded corners] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (v2) -- (f1) node [near end,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (f1) -- (v3) node [near start,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (f1) -- (v4) node [near start,below] {$2$};
        \draw[->] (v3) -- (f2) node [near end,above] {$1$};
        \draw[->] (f2) -- (v5) node [near start,above] {$1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]